# NextJS API routes how to handle multiple requests with MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, api, next.js

I have an API route. Inside of this route I handle requests coming from my components with MongodDB. My problem is that I am sending a PUT request from one of my components to that route and it is working. But now I want to send another PUT request from another component. How will I achieve this?

```
if (req.method === "PUT") {
    try {
        const { _id, id, change } = req.body;

        let set = `settings.$[el].${id}`;

        const data = await db
            .collection("Todos")
            .updateOne(
                { _id: _id },
                { $set: { [set]: change } },
                { arrayFilters: [{ "el._id": id }] }
            );
        res.status(201).json(data);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Unable to instert the data." });
    }
}
```

This is for my one request and now I want to send another one but also with another data. If I send it there will conflict so it fails. Some basic solutions I found but they are not sustainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create a new route `/api/newRoute`.

Another way is when you send the request add to its body a variable that differentiates between the two. For example:

```
body: {
 // your original data
 type: "newType" // this variable can be named anything you like
}
```

In the api route you can use the following code example:

```
if (req.method === "PUT" && req.body.type == "newType") {
    try {
    // your new code
  } catch (err) {
    // your new code
  }
}
```

Comment: I did it the second way. I just wondered that is there any other solutions or am I right. Thank you.

Comment: @SerdarGökhanBAKIRCI in programming usually there's many ways to do the same thing, and the ones I suggested are the ways I know. There might other ways I'm not aware of though.